# Non-cyclic Galois groups over the field of formal Laurent series in positive characteristic

Tags: galois-theory, positive-characteristic

This should be an easy question, but I am unfortunately not able to give an answer, so I am sorry if this is not the appropriate level for the site.

Let $C$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0.$ Let $C((T))$ be the field of formal Laurent series over $C.$ Suppose that $f(X) \in C((T))[X]$ is a polynomial such that $f(X) = \Pi_{i=1}^r (X-\alpha_i)^{e_i}$ with $\alpha_i \in C$ and $e_i \geq 1$ for $i=1 , \ldots r.$ Consider the polynomial
$$F(T,X) = f(X)-T.$$
My question is:
Can we choose $f(X)$ such that the polynomial $F$ is separable and the inertia group of the polynomial $F$ over the prime $T$ is **not** generated by a permutation $\sigma$ of cycle type $(e_1,\ldots,e_r)?$

My initial hope was to use extensions of $C(T),$ the function field over $C(T),$ coming from ramified coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1_{C}.$ However, when going to the completion, I got something which was cyclic, generated by a permutation $\sigma$ of cycle type as above.